# Vue 3: Using Blurhash as placeholder during image loading

Tags: javascript, image, vue.js, npm, vuejs3

I'm trying to add a Blurhash as placeholder during image loading using Vue 3, but I can't find a right way to do it. I tried using `vue-blurhash` package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-blurhash, but it didn't work, because it seems like it only supports Vue 2 and it's been deprecated as well.

What I did is I manually prepared the image hashes using https://blurha.sh/, then I put them into my database and I added an `v-if` statement to the `ItemBlurHashImg` component that I made, so that when the image is still loading, I want to display a Blurhash version of the image. The hash can be accessed through `data.blurhash`.

I know I'm doing it wrong, so I ask kindly for ideas of how to do it and a possible solution.

ItemCard.vue:

```
<template>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card__item">
            <ItemBlurHashImg
                v-if="!isLoaded"
                class="card__image"
                :hash="data.blurhash"
                width="15.625rem" />
            <img v-else
                class="card__image"
                :src="getSrc('.jpg')"
                :alt="data.alt"
                width="15.625rem"
                loading="lazy" />
            <div class="card__content">
                <h2 class="card__title">{{ data.title }}</h2>
                <p class="card__text">{{ data.text }}</p>
                <router-link class="card__link" :to="{ name: 'Home' }"
                    >View more</router-link
                >
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { onMounted, ref } from 'vue';
import ItemBlurHashImg from '@/components/SkeletonLoaders/ItemBlurHashImg.vue';

const props = defineProps(['data']);

const isLoaded = ref(false);

const getSrc = ext => {
    return new URL(
        `../assets/images/recipe/${props.data.image}${ext}`,
        import.meta.url
    ).href;
};

onMounted(() => {
    const img = new Image(getSrc('.jpg'));
    img.onload = () => {
        isLoaded.value = true;
    };
    img.src = getSrc('.jpg');
});
</script>

<style lang="scss">
.card {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 45px;
    align-items: center;
    &__item {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        color: $c-black;
        border-radius: $br-rounded;
        max-width: 22.5625rem;
        height: 30.25rem;
        background-color: $c-white;
    }
    &__image {
        border-top-left-radius: $br-rounded;
        border-top-right-radius: $br-rounded;
        display: block;
        min-width: 100%;
        height: 15rem;
        object-fit: cover;
    }
}
</style>
```

ItemBlurHashImg.vue:

```
<template>
    // some code...
</template>

<script setup>
const props = defineProps(['hash']);
</script>
```